# How to sum two tables of different dimensions in R?

Tags: r

I want to sum two tables in **R**, but they have different valid categories, which produces two different dimensions. How can I add them up?

Example:

```
table(VA)
  1   2   3   4   6   7   8   9  10 
652   1 300 777   9 615 167  26  67

table(VB)
 1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9   10 
 285    5  282  367    1   12  289  129   33 1118 

table(V2A)+table(V2B)
```

> Error in table(cx$V2A) + table(cx$V2B) : non-conformable arrays

What can I do to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess VA and VB are vectors. To effectively sum the tables, all you need to do is this:

```
table(c(VA,VB))
```

---

```
> VA <- sample(1:10,20,replace=TRUE)
> VB <- sample(1:10,20,replace=TRUE)
> table(VA)
VA
 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  9 10 
 1  3  3  2  3  2  2  2  2 
> table(VB)
VB
 1  2  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 
 1  2  2  2  4  3  1  2  3 
> table(c(VA,VB))

 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 
 2  5  3  4  5  6  5  1  4  5
```